# Can we add/affect programmatically html elements with dojo toolkit?

Tags: javascript, dojo

i have a input like this :

```
<input type="text" name="mailSubject"
         value="" />
```

i want it to be like this :

```
<input type="text" name="mailSubject"
        dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
        required="true"
        value="" />
```

but, i dont want to create a new input, juste to update the existing one adding the dojo stuff?
is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
var foo = new dijit.form.ValidationTextBox(/* Object? */ params, /* DomNode|String */ srcNodeRef);
```

As you can see, srcNodeRef can be either an element or an element's ID. So you could pass it your `<input>`'s ID and it should be replaced by dojo.

http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/form/ValidationTextBox.html